# Falha ao passar da verificação (data.success)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Eu possuo o seguinte código:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url : "chat/updates/",
        async : true,
        cache : false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                alert(data)
                thread = data.messages;
                senders = data.senders;
                $.each(thread, function() {
                    if($("#chat-box").is(":visible")){
                        chatbuddy = $("#chat_buddy_id").val();
                        if(this.sender == chatbuddy){
                            li = '<li class="'+ this.type +'"><img src="assets/images/thumbs/'+this.avatar+'" class="avt img-responsive">\
<div class="message">\
<span class="chat-arrow"></span>\
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chat-name">'+this.name+'</a>&nbsp;\
<span class="chat-datetime">at '+this.time+'</span>\
<span class="chat-body">'+this.body+'</span></div></li>';
                            $('ul.chat-box-body').append(li);
                            $('ul.chat-box-body').animate({scrollTop: $('ul.chat-box-body').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
                            //Mark this message as read
                            $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: base + "chat/mark_read", data: {id: this.msg}});
                        }
                        else{
                            from = this.sender;
                            $.each(senders, function() {
                                if(this.user == from){
                                    $(".chat-group").find('span[rel="'+from+'"]').text(this.count);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        from = this.sender;
                        $.each(senders, function() {
                            if(this.user == from){
                                $(".chat-group").find('span[rel="'+from+'"]').text(this.count);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

                var audio = new Audio('assets/notify/notify.mp3').play();
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, error) { 
            console.log(error); 
        }
    }
);

}, 2000);
```

o metodo `GET` está me retornando o seguinte JSON:

```
{"success":true,"messages":[{"msg":"57","sender":"2","recipient":"1","mensagem":"oi","time":"Nov 13, 2015, 6:17 pm","tipo":"receive","nome":""},{"msg":"58","sender":"2","recipient":"1","mensagem":"oi","time":"Nov 13, 2015, 6:18 pm","tipo":"receive","nome":""}],"senders":[{"user":2,"count":2}]}
```

porém ali no `if(data.success)` ele não passa na verificação! Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou depurar pelo navegador? Coloque um breakpoint ali e execute sua pagina e veja o que é retornado no data.sucess.

Comment: eu já tentei dar um alert, e retorna como undefined !

Comment: @WesleyIgor não rola dar esse alert porque o em ajax, o a vem da palavra assíncrono. Pra você verificar se o dado está chegando dá uma olhada na tab networking do chrome developer tools, procurando pela requisição feita a /chat/updates

Comment: só tentei dar o alert pra testar o data.success ... mas como você pode ver o GET está me retornando o valor de success, mas não passa na validacao.. alguem sabe me dizer o pq ?

Comment: Faz o que eu te falei, roda seu site, abre o console do firefox apertando control+shift+i e muda para tab "depurar. Seleciona seu js e declara o `var retorno = data.sucess` logo acima do `if` da validacao. Coloque um breakpoint do lado do if(duplo clique logo ao lado da linha) e executa sua pagina. Quando parar, você verá o que o data.sucess está retornando. Se não parar, é porque a requisição está com erro.

Answer (score 0):

Galera só foi inserir o seguinte no controlador.

```js
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```